# Reference for NIM-rep theory for non-commutative fusion rings?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, noncommutative-rings, conformal-field-theory, fusion-categories

The literature on nonnegative integer matrix representations (NIM-reps) seems to be focused on commutative fusion rings, since a primary motivation there is for rational conformal field theory (RCFT).  For instance [Terry Gannon - Boundary Conformal Field Theory and Fusion Ring Representations](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0106105).

Is there a reference for NIMrep in non-commutative fusion rings? In particular, I would like to know if a simultaneous Perron–Frobenius eigenvector still exists.

Comment: For completeness, could you say what "NIM-rep" (or NIMrep?) and RCFT mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my post to explain these acronyms.